# Sequelize mySQL to MS SQL migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

We're moving from mySQL to MS SQL db and using Sequelize in NodeJS as an api.

Issues start when using the `.findOrCreate` method.

What I expect when calling an endpoint is that the record that I pass in the body of the request will get created, since it doesnt exist in the db. 
The ID field in the db is pk and identity(0,1).

Sequelize is trying to insert into that field, how can I prevent that?

This is the code in the route:

```
model.table1
    .findOrCreate({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id
      },
      defaults: {
        field1: req.body.field1,
        field2: req.body.field2,
        field3: req.body.field3
      }
    })
    .spread((rowFound, created) => {
      if (created) {
        rowFound.get({ plain: true });
      } else {
        rowFound.update({
          field1: req.body.field1,
        field2: req.body.field2,
        field3: req.body.field3
        });
      }
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
      res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
    });
```

This is the model:

```
module.exports = sequelize => {
  const table1 = sequelize.define(
    'table1',
    {
      field1: Sequelize.STRING(10),
      field2: Sequelize.STRING(255),
      field3: Sequelize.STRING(300),
      id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    },
    {
      schema: 'dbo',
      tableName: 'table1',
      hasTrigger: true
    }
  );

  return table1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your model to the following:

```js
module.exports = sequelize => {
  const table1 = sequelize.define(
    'table1',
    {
      field1: Sequelize.STRING(10),
      field2: Sequelize.STRING(255),
      field3: Sequelize.STRING(300),
      id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    },
    {
      schema: 'dbo',
      tableName: 'table1',
      hasTrigger: true
    }
  );

  return table1;
};
```

Comment: Yeah I did try that but the `findOrCreate` still fails. What I ended up doing was splitting the functionality into 2 routes. `POST` and `PUT` and used the `.create` sequelize method to create a new row in the `POST`, and `.findAll` followed by `.update` in the `PUT` to update an existing row.

Comment: Did you try without the `hasTrigger: true` ?

Comment: Can't, it does have a trigger that needs handled